# Past tense and past perfect in essays?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-participles

I'm writing an essay (fiction) in past tense.

- He went. She slept. I said. etc.

**How do I correctly express activity before the time of action ?**

- He went home. But before that he had eaten a sandwich.
- He went home. But before that he has been eating a sandwich.
- I lay in my bed and remembered the last dream I had have.
- I lay in my bed and remembered the last dream I have had.

Which one is correct ? Are both correct ? Do they express the same thing or something different ? Explanation ? Technical terms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"He went home. But before that he had eaten a sandwich." - the most technically correct answer - you use **past perfect tense** in its intended purpose.

"He went home. But before that he *has been eating a sandwich." - incorrect by the grammar rules, and I don't think **present perfect continuous** tense is very common in casual speech in this case.  I'd use **past perfect continuous** ("...he had been eating a sandwich").

"I lay in my bed and remembered the last dream I *had have." - I think the tense is right (**past perfect** again), but you got the past participle wrong - it should be "...I had had".

"I lay in my bed and remembered the last dream I *have had." - see the second case.

In general, it's also acceptable to use **Simple Past** in place of Past Perfect if the order of the events is clear - so "He went home. But before that, he ate a sandwich" and "I lay in my bed and remembered the last dream I had" would also be correct.

Answer (score 0):

> - He went home. But before that he had eaten a sandwich.
> - He went home. But before that he has been eating a sandwich.

The first one is more correct, but I believe that it would be better to write

- He went home. But before that he ate a sandwich.

This is past tense.

> - I lay in my bed and remembered the last dream I had have.
> - I lay in my bed and remembered the last dream I have had.

None of these are correct. The correct would be:

- I lay in my bed and remembered the last dream I had had.

because you need past tense (first had) for the past tense of your verb (second had).

Comment: You say _"first one is more correct"_. What do you think about the second sentence: _He went home. But before that he has been eating a sandwich._?